# How can I prevent the contents of my website from being displayed after a user logs out, and without proper authentication?

Tags: flask, flask-login

When a user logs out, a certain page is redirected, and when I use the browser's back button, the contents are seen. Why is that so?

```
@admins.route("/logout")

def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

Comment: You should protect the pages you don't want to be visible by verifying if the user is logged in before displaying those pages.